# zalenium deployment in kubernet issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, zalenium

Trying to deploy zalenium in kubernet cluster using yaml .getting
   this issue.

here I have added the yaml file also.

please let me know m i doing something wrong?

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: zalenium
  spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: zalenium
       role: grid
   spec:
     # Added to test manually https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/246
     securityContext:
       fsGroup: 1000
     containers:
       - name: zalenium
         image: docker.repo1.uhc.com/gcl/zalenium:latest
         args:
           - start
           - '--desiredContainers'
           - '2'
           - '--screenWidth'
           - '1440'
           - '--screenHeight'
           - '810'
           - '--seleniumImageName'
           - 'docker.repo1.uhc.com/gcl/selenium:latest'
           - '--maxTestSessions'
           - '4'
         env:
           - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST
             value: 50m
           - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT
             value: 100m
           - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST
             value: 100Mi
           - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT
             value: 5Gi
           - name: OVERRIDE_WAIT_TIME
             value: 5m
         resources:
           requests:
             cpu: 50m
             memory: 100Mi
         ports:
           - containerPort: 4444
             protocol: TCP
         volumeMounts:
           - name: zalenium-data
             mountPath: /home/seluser/videos
           - name: zalenium-mounted
             mountPath: /tmp/mounted
     volumes:
         - name: zalenium-data
           emptyDir: {}
         - name: zalenium-mounted
           emptyDir: {}    
     securityContext:
       runAsUser: 1000
     serviceAccountName: marora23
     serviceAccount: marora23
```

issue... .............15:56:01.942 [main] INFO 
   d.z.e.z.c.k.KubernetesContainerClient - Initialising Kubernetes
   support ............GridLauncher failed to start after 1 minute,
   failing...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time
   Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

```
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
```

--:--:--     0   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 100   404    0   404    0     0   1348      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1346         Zalenium - 502

```
   - Bad Gateway
    </title>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   <style>
   h1 { text-align: center; }
   address { text-align: center; }   </style> </head> <body>   <h1>502

   - Bad Gateway
    </h1> <hr> <address>nginx/1.10.3 - Zalenium 3.141.59w</address> </body> </html>


   enter code here
```

Comment: Hi sarada, welcome to SO. Your question is at risk of closure because it does not provide any troubleshooting steps that you have already taken, log messages, your code, or any information that could enable someone to help you, or provide a question that would be valuable to future readers. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for a good question, paying especial attention to the [MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide on [https://medium.com](https://medium.com/@abhidp/deploy-a-selenium-grid-on-google-cloud-platform-using-kubernetes-4ea49747392f) that you might be interested. That's explain how to deploy Selenium on GKE.